# Access javascript object depending on its property

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

With the function below it's possible to get the `translate` property **by knowing the name** of the parent object. If there's no object matching, I'd like the function to pick the object with the property of the translated country text. The solution should be in jQuery/Javascript. This is how far I can get and I don't know where to go from here.

```
  function getCurrency(country) {
    var currency = {
      'Förenade Arabemiraten' : currData = {
        'code' : 'AED',
        'info' : 'Dirham',
        'translate' : 'United Arab Emirates'
      },
      'Afghanistan' : currData = {
        'code' : 'AFN',
        'info' : 'Afghani',
        'translate' : 'Afghanistan'
      },
      'Albanien' : currData = {
        'code' : 'ALL',
        'info' : 'Lek',
        'translate' : 'Albania'
      }
    };
    console.log(currency[country]);
    if(currency[country] !== undefined) {
      return currency[country];
    }
    else {
      for (var key in currency) {
        console.log(key);
      }
    }  
  }

var foo = getCurrency('Albanien');
// alerts 'Albania'
alert(foo.translate);

var bar = getCurrency('Albania');
alert(bar.translate);
// undefined, should output 'Albanien' and all the object properties (info, code)
```

JS Bin: http://jsbin.com/enezaz/1/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there:

```
for (var key in currency) {
    if(currency[key].translate == country) {
        return currency[key];
    }
}
```

Also, you should remove `currData =` from your literals; it's just creating a global variable, not a property named `currData`.

---

To also return the country name, I suggest you return a new object that includes it:

```
function getCurrency(country) {
    var currency = {
      'Förenade Arabemiraten' : currData = {
        'code' : 'AED',
        'info' : 'Dirham',
        'translate' : 'United Arab Emirates'
      },
      'Afghanistan' : currData = {
        'code' : 'AFN',
        'info' : 'Afghani',
        'translate' : 'Afghanistan'
      },
      'Albanien' : currData = {
        'code' : 'ALL',
        'info' : 'Lek',
        'translate' : 'Albania'
      }
    };
    if(currency[country] !== undefined) {
      return {
        country: country,
        countryData : currency[country]
      };
    } else {
      for (var key in currency) {
        if(currency[key].translate == country) {
          return {
            country: key,
            countryData : currency[key]
          };
        } 
      }
    }  
  }

var foo = getCurrency('Albanien');
// alerts 'Albanien'
alert(foo.country);
// alerts 'Albania'
alert(foo.data.translate);

var bar = getCurrency('Albania');
// alerts 'Albanien'
alert(bar.country);
// alerts 'Albania'
alert(bar.data.translate);
```

Comment: That's just great! I updated the JS Bin. Is this what you meant? http://jsbin.com/enezaz/5/edit 

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Glad to help!

Comment: Is it also possible to make `bar` output `'Albanien'` (the object name) as stated in the question? :) Thank you.

Comment: It would be strange if the function returned different formats depending on the case. See my updates.

Comment: Thank you once again @bfavaretto It seems like `bar.country` and `bar.countryData.translate` both returns Albania though. I updated the JS Bin http://jsbin.com/enezaz/6/edit

Comment: Changed `country: country` to `country: key` and now I'm happy with the result. :) Cheers

Comment: @estrar You're correct, I fixed the answer too. Thanks for letting me know, I'm glad you figured it out!